# Cronjob can't run php perfectly

Tags: php, cron

I have good .php file when run directly via address bar browser.
But not process perfectly when run via cron job, may be it's just process first query msyql/first loop.

there is any special configuration for it?

My cron setup is

```
0 * * * * wget --spider -O - http://domain.com/cronjob >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: What errors does your cron logs show? `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: sorry, permission denied.. I will try resolving it

Answer (score 1):

See below example that is run your file on per minute

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/<your-file-name>

< and > are removed in <your-file-name>
```